# How to exclude div from firing this event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use code bellow to get the text that user has double clicked:

```
<html>
    <script language="javascript">
        document.ondblclick = function() {
            alert(GetSelectedText());
        }

        function GetSelectedText() {
            if (document.selection) {
                return document.selection.createRange().text;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="should_trigger_event">sample of a text!</div>
        <div id="should_not_trigger_event">sample of a text!</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I want to `ondblclick` event just fire up for div with id: `should_trigger_event` and not for div with id: `should_not_trigger_event`

How can we achieve that?

Comment: `document.getElementById('should_trigger_event').ondblclick`

Comment: Try this example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQQhf/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple using jQuery :

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#should_trigger_event').on('dblclick',function(){
      alert(GetSelectedText());
   });
});

    function GetSelectedText() {
        if (document.selection) {
            return document.selection.createRange().text;
        }     
    }
</script>
```

More Information on 
 
[jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) 
[jQuery double click binding](http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/)

Comment: if I replace your code with <script>...</script> section of my code, it gives me error: the value of property $ is null or undefined

Comment: you need to give jquery file link ...  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: see this for reference http://www.w3schools.com/jQuery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide

Comment: @wiki probably you haven't included `jquery`, then why did you tag it in the question..?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you bind click event using element id:

```
$(function(){
  $('#should_trigger_event').click(function(){
     if (document.selection) {
             return document.selection.createRange().text;
}});});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly assign the handler to the div you want to include…

```
var div = document.getElementById('should_trigger_event');
div.ondblclick = function() {
    alert(GetSelectedText());
}
```

or if you want the handler for whole document, you can check `target` in event object

```
document.ondblclick = function(e) {
if(e.target.id != 'should_not_trigger_event')
        alert(GetSelectedText());
    }
```

Comment: for your first code, it gives me this error: unable to set property 'ondblclick' of undefined or null reference; and for your second code this error: unable to get property 'target' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @wiki both [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/XpmLj/) and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/XpmLj/1/) seems to be working fine...